# Different Reports with same "Click()" working differently - can't find why

Tags: vba, ms-access

A while ago I created a "prefab" Access Database (Contact tracking) and as usual, some of the code within is awkward.  Now I'm trying to make some edits, add some reports and forms, and a couple other functions.  Everything has gone well so far, but I came across the problem I just can't wrap my head around and my eyes are starting to cross trying to find out what's wrong.  Both of these reports are intended to open the exact same data based on their own text.

**Here is the code:**
`rptListings`- *This works perfectly*

```
Private Sub Text107_Click()
On Error GoTo Text107_Click_Err

    If (IsNull(Text107)) Then
        Beep
    End If
    If (Not IsNull(Text107)) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContactDetails", acNormal, "", "[ID]=" & Me.txtContactID, , acDialog
    End If

Text107_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Text107_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Text107_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

`rptNeedToContact`- *This doesn't work*

```
Private Sub txtFullName_Click()
On Error GoTo txtFullName_Click_Err

    If (IsNull(txtFullName)) Then
        Beep
    End If
    If (Not IsNull(txtFullName)) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContactDetails", acNormal, "", "[ID]=" & Me.txtContactID, , acDialog
    End If

txtFullName_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

txtFullName_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume txtFullName_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

The error itself implies that there is something with the "OnLoad" for the form itself.  So here is that code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Form_Load_Err

    If (IsNull(OpenArgs)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (Not CurrentProject.IsTrusted) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TempVars.Add "NewData", Mid(Nz(OpenArgs), InStr(Nz(OpenArgs), "=") + 1)
    TempVars.Add "Space", InStrRev(TempVars!NewData, " ")
    On Error Resume Next
    If (TempVars!Space = 0 And TempVars!NewData <> "") Then
        [Last Name] = TempVars!NewData
    End If
    If (TempVars!Space > 0) Then
        [First Name] = Left(TempVars!NewData, TempVars!Space - 1)
        [Last Name] = Mid(TempVars!NewData, TempVars!Space + 1)
    End If
    TempVars.Remove "NewData"
    TempVars.Remove "Space"

Form_Load_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Form_Load_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Form_Load_Exit

End Sub
```

**Here's an image of the error**
[image: The Error]
**Showing the box is actually a textbox**
[image: It's a textbox]

**EDIT:** Here is a Google Drive link to the database.  I removed all personal information other than names.  [GOOGLE DRIVE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GsqPTV3DDAu64lpXD4dcyRTvv-LEvXsY)

Comment: So error is triggered on `Private Sub txtFullName_Click()` line? Code execution doesn't even enter the procedure? Have you step-debugged? I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Try going to the Event Tab on the Property sheet, and confirm your event handler points to your specific sub. I've had this happen once or twice, rebuilding the app by importing all the objects/data worked for me.

Comment: To locate problem you can try `Debug` - `Compile` menu option in VBA editor.

Comment: Creating a new report and copypasta all the stuff over to the new report worked.  Not sure why the other one was broken, but it works.  Deleted my old comments.  Anyone have any clue why it would work after copypasta and not before?

Comment: One problem I see (but it is the same on both forms), is that you should be using `IsNull(Me.Text107)` and not `IsNull(Text107)` for all instances where a form's VBA code references the form's controls.

Comment: @SunKnight0  That might be a good habit for various reasons, but it is not necessarily a "problem".  It will resolve to the same object if there are no conflicting names.  Otherwise it might be even better to type`Me.Text107.Value`.

Comment: Please do not post links to the actual database.  Although I could not find anything to the contrary in a review of meta and help, it is not customary to provide links to the database.  Access databases contain executable code and it is inadvisable for anyone to actually download and open/execute such a file.

Comment: Lastly, I'll point back to Ryan Wildry's answer.  Your last edit and comments made no mention of it, but I think the error in your question points to the event "binding" on the Event Tab, not necessarily to the code in the event handler.  Regrettably, Access (and Office VBA apps) do not always properly distinguish between the event, the binding to the code, and the event handling code itself.  It is worth checking all aspect when having problems like this.